# Google Maps API not being loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Recently I've experienced that the Google Maps API does not load on several of my projects.

Sometimes it will load, but most of the time I get a `GET http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3.5&callback=readyMap net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` error in the Google Chrome developer console.

Since it fails so often I started loading it async, which prevents it from slowing the page load.

```
function loadScript() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src =    'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3.5&callback=readyMap';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

I've tried loading it in all ways I know, but still encounter this timeout-issue.

Anybody have any experience in this area, and can point me in the right direction as to what I have to do? Is it a request limitations issue? Seems weird if it is, as very few of the sites have reached production yet, and I'm the only one who views the map.

Thanks in advance!

Tor

Comment: Maybe this post could be usefull : http://superuser.com/questions/719559/why-cant-chrome-load-a-web-page-err-name-not-resolved

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Surely there must be a better way than this, as I've tested on multiple of my colleagues computers, and they encounter the same issue. Also it does not seems to be working in Safari or Firefox either.

Comment: v=3.5 is very out of date and isn't what you'll be getting any more.  The version Google will be giving you is 3.19, the 'frozen' version, see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning  You could just specify v=3 to get the most recent release version.

Comment: @tormorten where's your `readyMap` function?

Comment: The most recent google maps examples are including the script here `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>`.